# Windows freezes when dealing with a large (200 GB) file but OS X does not. Why?

Tags: macos, windows-10, freeze, file-management

I have one very large file (around 200 GB) that I have interacted with on both Windows 10 and OS X. I ran into the following issue: Windows freezes for a minute after opening the folder in Explorer, while OS X has no issues and I can pretty much immediately interact with the file in Finder. Copying the file between external drives makes the Windows machine freeze for about two hours before copying, while the OS X machine does not (and can still be used). **What aspect of file handling causes this big difference between the two machines?**

Because of Windows freezing I have not been able to look at the resource monitor for Disk, CPU or Memory performances.

The machines are a 64-bit Windows 10 PC (6 GB RAM) and a late 2011 MacBook Pro (8 GB RAM).

Comment: This is not normal for a Windows PC. Windows 10 is still beta software in my opinion, they have had several complete upgrades to the OS since RTM in July. I see forums full of usb bugs among others, and the bugs vary depending on hardware,

Comment: This is a WAY too open ended question that would best be served by a google search of [differences between windows 10 and mac os x](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=differences%20between%20windows%2010%20and%20mac%20os%20x&oq=differences%20between%20windows%2010%20and%20mac%20os%20x%20&aqs=chrome..69i57.16527j1j7)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, SaxDaddy. However, I have already done a number of google searches of the sort, with more specific terms than you suggested, and I have not been able to find ANY useful answers. Thus I came here. I have also tried to make my question as specific as possible by focusing on the possible differences in file handling, which seems to be the issue (I could be wrong). Suggestions for improving the question are welcome, if possible.